# Auto populate fields containing Files

Tags: javascript, php, html

> **Note:** The answers below reflect the state of legacy browsers in 2009.
>
> Now you can actually do it.
>   See the answer in this question:
> [How to set file input value programatically (i.e.: when drag-dropping files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232/584192)

I have two input field of type FILE.
Is it possible that if user browses and chooses  a file  in one field ,that same file gets chosen in other field automatically.

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set file input using javascript due to security reasons.
Please check [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html).

Comment: I think this is different case.In my case,user already is giving input in form of one file.I just need to somehow copy that file.

Comment: You cannot set the value to the input type file due to security reasons. please check with that url. I tried now. https://jsfiddle.net/sz66wtug/ @HarshitBansal

Comment: You can clone the element and then change the name using jQuery but it is not a good practice to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cloning an element works for you. But it seems like a dirty workaround.

```js
function clone() {
  var input = document.getElementById("in");
  var divvi = document.getElementById("divvi");
  divvi.appendChild(input.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<div id="divvi">
  <input id="in" onchange="clone()" type="file" name="file1" />
</div>
```